# Expected Value in joint probability distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I am very puzzled as to how they arrived at μ=2/5 in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxsmL.png). I understand that μ is just expected value which would mean summing x or y with its possible realizations, but if x and y are max. 1, and integrating f_x(x) just gives us 1, wouldn't EV also be 1 then? This seems very obvious, however, I just can't see how they arrived at 2/5, which just proves I conceptually don't really understand it.. Any hints/help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: "*and integrating $f_X(x)$ just gives us $1$, wouldn't EV also be $1$ then?*"  Look again at your definition of expected value.  It is not the integral of $f_X(x)$ over the support, but rather the integral of $\color{darkred}{x\cdot}f_X(x)$ over the support.

Comment: Ahh okay, I see thank you! I was multiplying the integral by 1 since I assumed that to be x rather than intergrating x from 0 to 1 along with f_x(x).

Comment: great, thank you!